# Create offline OSX application from Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, offline

I was recently building an internal business database web app using Ruby on Rails 4 and Postgres. The plan was to make the app available to all our employees using Devise for authentication and hosting on Heroku.

Toward the end of development, a request was made to include some highly sensitive information in the app including social security numbers, etc. Thus, instead of heavily worrying about online security we are planning to make this app only run locally on one Mac and not have it available online. The app will only be used about 5 times a month by one person. Instead of requiring that person to launch a postgres server and a webserver via terminal (such as "rails server"), is there a way to package the entire Rails web app and database in to an application so it could be run similar to other OSX apps?

If anyone knows a PC solution instead, that is also a (less preferred) option.

At this point, we realize we should have developed a xcode app, but now that the development is mostly complete with some tricky UI, we would rather not have to recreate the functionality in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't used it myself, what your describing sounds pretty close to what [Rubymotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/tour/how-it-works/) offers